# sum of :$\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^k}{2k-1} \cos(2k-1)$

Tags: complex-analysis, fourier-analysis, fourier-series, dirichlet-series

How can I find the sum of :$$\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^k}{2k-1} \cos(2k-1)$$

I don't fully understand the parseval identity so I am asking if we can use it to find the sum, and if so, how I should use it.
Is there a Fourier series we know the convergence to a function that can help?

Comment: Parseval identity is a statement about norm, and is a sort of pythagorean theorem with infinitly many squared coefficients. As they are squared, all terms will be non-negative, so your series cannot be deduced from Parseval identity I guess

Comment: yes that's right. do i need to look for a function that has a Fourier series?

Comment: Isn't $x$ missing in the cosine?

Comment: One easy way to do it is to expand $1$ in sine series on $[0, \pi]$ by extending it to be an odd function on $[-\pi, 0]$ and then take $x=\pi/2-1$ as $\sin ((2k+1)(\pi/2-1))=(-1)^k\cos(2k+1))$;

Comment: @user376343 no it's not missing

Comment: One possibility is to consider it as the real part of a power series in the complex domain

Comment: Mathematica evaluates the sum as $\sum\limits_{k=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^k}{2 k-1} \cos (2 k-1)=-\frac{\pi }{4}$ which provides the result but not much insight as to the derivation.

Comment: i've tried it too and saw that -pi/4 is the sum but how i get it? im trying to use the Fourier series of |x| now

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Recall the Maclaurin series of arctangent, valid for $|z|\leq 1,$ $z\neq\pm i$:
$$
\arctan(z) = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^kz^{2k+1}}{2k+1}
$$
$$
-\arctan(z) = \sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^kz^{2k-1}}{2k-1}
$$Put $z=e^{i}$ and take the real part:
$$
\Re(-\arctan(e^i)) = \Re\left( \sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^k(e^{i})^{2k-1}}{2k-1}\right)=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^k\cos(2k-1)}{2k-1}
$$The LHS evaluates to $-1\cdot \pi/4$, since the argument (angle) is $1$ and $\arctan(1)=\pi/4$.

Comment: thank you, is there the possibility of using the series fourier of |x| to get to the same result?

Comment: @Shane better to use the fourier series of the rectangular wave

Comment: @Integrand Sorry, I can not figure out how you obtain $$\arctan(e^i) = \arctan \left[ \cos(1) + i \sin(1) \right]$$ How to determine it?

Comment: @BowPark splitting into real and imaginary parts, we have
$$
\arctan(e^i)=\frac{1}{2} \arctan\left(\frac{\cos
   (1)}{1-\sin (1)}\right)+\frac{1}{2} \arctan\left(\frac{\cos
   (1)}{1+\sin (1)}\right)+i \left(\frac{1}{4} \log \left(2-2 \sin (1)\right)-\frac{1}{4} \log \left(2+2 \sin (1)\right)\right)
$$Take the real part and use the arctan angle-addition formula.

Comment: @BowPark A nicer way: if $\theta$ is real, $\Re\left(\arctan(e^{i\theta}) \right)= \pi/4\cdot \text{sign}(\cos(\theta))$.

Comment: @Integrand I am not able to follow your steps. Sorry. I posted a [dedicated question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3695166/132192).

Comment: How do you show that series converges for $|z|=1$ except when $z=\pm i$. I understand that $\arctan z$ has singularities at $z=\pm i$ so that radius of convergence is $1$ thus series converges if $|z|<1$. The case $|z|=1$ requires more analysis.

Comment: @Paramanand Singh Dirichlet's Theorem

Comment: Oh yes, I infact used the same Dirichlet test in a question linked with the current question being discussed here.

Answer (score 0):

$\newcommand{\bbx}[1]{\,\bbox[15px,border:1px groove navy]{\displaystyle{#1}}\,}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$
\begin{align}
&\bbox[10px,#ffe]{\sum_{k = 1}^{\infty}{\pars{-1}^{k} \over 2k -1}\cos(2k-1)} =
\ic\sum_{k = 1}^{\infty}{\ic^{2k - 1} \over 2k - 1}\cos(2k - 1)
\\[5mm] = &\
\ic\sum_{k = 1}^{\infty}{\ic^{k} \over k}\cos(k)\,
{1^{k} - \pars{-1}^{k} \over 2 } =
-\,\Im\sum_{k = 1}^{\infty}{\ic^{k} \over k}\cos(k) =
-\,\Im\sum_{k = 1}^{\infty}{\ic^{k} \over k}{\expo{\ic k} + \expo{-\ic k}
\over 2}
\\[5mm] = &\
-\,{1 \over 2}\,\Im\sum_{k = 1}^{\infty}{\pars{\ic\expo{\ic}}^{k} \over k} -
{1 \over 2}\,\Im\sum_{k = 1}^{\infty}{\pars{\ic\expo{-\ic}}^{k} \over k}
\\[5mm] = &\
{1 \over 2}\,\Im\ln\pars{1 - \ic\expo{\ic}} +
{1 \over 2}\,\Im\ln\pars{1 - \ic\expo{-\ic}}
\\[5mm] = &\
{1 \over 2}\,\Im\ln\pars{1 + \sin\pars{1} - \ic\cos\pars{1}} +
{1 \over 2}\,\Im\ln\pars{1 - \sin\pars{1} - \ic\cos\pars{1}}
\\[5mm] = &\
-\,{1 \over 2}\,\arctan\pars{\cos\pars{1} \over 1 + \sin\pars{1}} -
{1 \over 2}\,\arctan\pars{\cos\pars{1} \over 1 - \sin\pars{1}}
\\[5mm] = &\
-\,{1 \over 2}\,\bracks{{\pi \over 2} - \arctan\pars{1 + \sin\pars{1} \over \cos\pars{1}}} -
{1 \over 2}\arctan\pars{\cos\pars{1} \over 1 - \sin\pars{1}}
\\[5mm] = &\
\color{red}{-\,{\pi \over 4}} +
{1 \over 2}\
\overbrace{\bracks{\arctan\pars{1 + \sin\pars{1} \over \cos\pars{1}} -
\arctan\pars{\cos\pars{1} \over 1 - \sin\pars{1}}}}
^{\ds{\ =\ \color{red}{0}}}\label{1}\tag{1}
\\[5mm] = &\ \bbx{-\,{\pi \over 4}}\
\approx -0.7854
\end{align}
The brackets in (\ref{1}) vanishes out because
$\ds{{1 + \sin\pars{1} \over \cos\pars{1}} - {\cos\pars{1} \over 1 - \sin\pars{1}} = \color{red}{0}}$.

See
[A & S $\ds{\bf\color{black}{4.4.34}}$](http://people.math.sfu.ca/%7Ecbm/aands/page_80.htm)