# Determine if $\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^k}{2k-1} \cos(2k-1)$ is a convergent series

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, sequences-and-series, trigonometry

This series is from [another question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3693999/132192):

$$\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^k}{2k-1} \cos(2k-1)$$

There, its value $-\pi/4$ is immediately determined. But how to be sure, *a priori*, that the series would converge?

I am new as regards this topic. I tried the [Leibniz test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convergence_tests#Alternating_series_test), but it fails: due to the cosine, the series may not have alternating signs, even for large $n$. Then, how to determine if the series is convergent?

Comment: use $\cos(2k-1) \le 1$

Comment: @AdityaDwivedi So, you mean using the [direct comparison test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Direct_comparison_test) between the series $\frac{(-1)^k}{2k - 1}$ and $\frac{(-1)^k}{2k - 1} \cos (2k - 1)$?

Comment: yes i said that

Comment: @AdityaDwivedi Thank you. If you want, you can create an answer.

Comment: @AdityaDwivedi: that test works for. Series of positive terms.

Comment: actually $ -1 \le \cos(2k-1) \le 1$ should be used

Comment: You have accepted a wrong answer. You should try to learn more and fix it.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh Yes, this test is only available for series of positive terms. But aren't the series of absolute values $\displaystyle \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \left| \frac{(-1)^k }{2k-1} \right|$ and $\displaystyle \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \left| \frac{(-1)^k }{2k-1} \cos(2k - 1) \right|$ series of positive terms?

Comment: @BowPark Absolute value series $\sum\left|\frac{(-1)^k}{2k-1}\right|$ diverges.

Comment: @BowPark: your question is not so trivial to be answered in such a casual manner. In fact the inequalities written in this accepted answer are meaningless.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh I see that the ratio test is $1$ as regards $\sum \left| \frac{(-1)^k}{2k - 1} \right|$. If this is immediate (otherwise it would require another question), how do you obtain that it diverges?

Comment: Well compare the series with $\sum 1/k^p$ with $p=1$ and thus series diverges. Remember harmonic series.

Answer (score 1):

Let $$S_n=\sum_{k=1}^{n}(-1)^k\cos(2k-1)$$ and $$T_n=\sum_{k=1}^{n}\cos(2k-1)$$ so that $$S_n+T_n=2\sum_{k\text{ even}, k\leq n} \cos(2k-1)$$ and $$T_n-S_n=2\sum_{k\text{ odd}, k\leq n} \cos(2k-1)$$ Using the formula for sums of trigonometric series with arguments in arithmetic progression one can show that the above sums are bounded for all $n$ so that $S_n$ is also bounded.

Now use $a_n=1/(2n-1)$ so that $a_n$ decreases and tends to $0$ and $b_n=(-1)^{n}\cos(2n-1)$ and the sum $S_n=\sum_{k=1}^{n}b_k$ is bounded and by [Dirichlet test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet%27s_test) the series $\sum a_nb_n$ converges.